# Design idempotent unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit5, idempotent

I'm designing unit tests for the following method:

```
public void loadFile(Path filename) throws IOException {
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        Files.move(filename, filename.resolveSibling("ERROR_" + filename.getFileName()));
        return;
    }

    Files.delete(filename);
}
```

And I'm looking for a way of testing it without producing different results, since the input file is going to be either renamed or deleted after the execution test:

- If `RuntimeException` takes place, file is renamed.
- If execution goes as expected, file is deleted.

Either way, consecutive runs of the test will make it fail because file will be named different or it won't exist... How could I prevent that? Also, is there a way to verify `Files#move(Path, Path, CopyOption...)` and `Files#delete(Path)` were invoked?

Comment: For that I use the test setup and teardown methods to ensure the input is there before the test, and removed after.  As far as what gets tested, I will use some sort of coverage report to ensure what I want tested is tested.

Comment: 1. have original file, 2. before each test runs create temp dir and make copy of that file to a temp dir, 3. run test, 4. after each test destroy the temp dir. Look at `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` annotations for junit

Comment: @RobGoodwin :facepalm. That is an easy solution!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use new `@TempDir` annotation from `junit 5`.

[Docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDir.html):

> When the end of the scope of a temporary directory is reached, i.e. when the test method or class has finished execution, JUnit will attempt to recursively delete all files and directories in the temporary directory and, finally, the temporary directory itself.

In that case you test cases will look as the next:

```java
@Test
void loadsFileCorrectly(@TempDir Path temp) {
    final Path file = temp.resolve("testable.file");
    loadFile(file);
    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.notExists(file));
}

@Test
void loadsFileWithException(@TempDir Path temp) {
    final Path file = temp.resolve("testable.file");
    loadFile(file);
    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(file.resolveSibling("ERROR_" + file.getFileName())));
}
```

In both scenarios, the created files will be automatically deleted after execution.